# Hypergeometric: how do I construct a credibility interval around K (population successes) in R?

Tags: r, bayesian, hypergeometric-distribution, credible-interval

I have a problem for which I believe I should use the hypergeometric distribution, but I can't figure out how to do it in R.

Say I have a bag of marbles with known number ($N$) of marbles, but the number of successes (white marbles) in the bag ($K$) is unknown. I want to infer about K.

Given a sample from this population, where I see $n$ trials and $k$ successes, how do I infer something about the population $K$?

Ideally, I'd like to construct a prior distribution around $K$ and then use the sample to update it and get a Bayesian posterior credibility interval around $K$ (for a given credibility score $\alpha$), but I am struggling to complete this practically. I have read that the conjugate prior for the hypergeometric is the beta-binomial. I thought maybe there would be an R function or package that could take the prior parameters, and then update with a sample to give me a credibility interval, but haven't been able to find it.

If the Bayesian setting is difficult, perhaps a confidence interval would suffice... Can anyone either point me to some R functions or tutorials, or some resources that could help? Thanks.

EDIT: To add an example, I can do this in the case of the binomial distribution, to infer $p$, given a sample. I can construct a credibility interval with the `binom` package

```
k= 15
n= 25
library(binom)
binom.bayes(k, n, conf.level = .95, tol=.005, type="central")
# method  x  n shape1 shape2      mean     lower     upper  sig
#  bayes 15 25   15.5   10.5 0.5961538 0.4057793 0.7725105 0.05
```

To add a prior, because of the way updates work with the beta-binomial, I can just add counts to the $k$ and $n$ parameters according to the $a$ and $b$ parameters of the prior beta distribution.

In the beta-binomial example, $N$ is infinite, and I'm inferring $p$. What I want to do is take this exact situation and just extend it to the case where $N$ is finite (and known), and infer $K$ (which would be equivalent to inferring $p$). This changes the binomial to the hypergeometric.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been interested in this question, and I initially came up with a solution similar to Phil's, where

$$
P(K|k)=\frac{\frac{\binom{K}{k}*\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}}{\sum_{j=k}^{N-n+k} \frac{\binom{j}{k}*\binom{N-j}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}}
$$

Where the probability of *K* for a given *k* is the likelihood of *K* over the sum of the likelihoods of all *K*s. This feels right to me, but I haven't been able to prove that it is precisely the correct answer. However, if it is, then the PDF simplifies (after some handy Wolfram Alpha) to:

$$
f(K)=\frac{\binom{K}{k}*\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N-k}{n-k}* {}_2 F_1(k+1, n-N; k-N, 1)}
$$

However, since the combinations in the numerator and denominator can get rather large, I have found it helpful to use the following form for computation:

$$
f(K)=\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{K-k} \frac{(K+j)*(N-K-n+k+j)}{j*(N-K+j)}}{{}_2 F_1(k+1, n-N; k-N, 1)}
$$

The first and second moments are rather unwieldy, but do have a closed form:

$$
E[K]=\frac{(N-n)*(k+1)* {}_2 F_1 (k+2, n-N+1; k-N+1; 1)}{(N-k)* {}_2 F_1 (k+1, n-N; k-N; 1)}
$$
$$
E[K^2]=\left((2k+1)* {}_2 F_1 (k+2, n-N+1, k-N+1, 1) + \frac{(k+2)*(n-N+1)* {}_2 F_1 (k+3,n-N+2,k-N+2,1)}{k - N + 1}\right)*\frac{(k+1)*(n-N)}{(k - N)* {}_2 F_1 (k+1, n-N, k-N, 1)} + k^2
$$

Where ${}_2 F_1$ is the hypergeometric function.

I have not been able to find a better method for calculating the CDF than simply summing up the terms of the PDF, but if you do that, you should have everything you need for a confidence interval.

Also note that the special cases where *k*=0 and *k*=1 are much easier to develp and do not require using the hypergeometric function.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve your problem using the Maximum Likelihood method rather than the Bayesian method.  Just calculate the hypergeometric probability of finding k for a large number of values of K using your known values of k, N and n.  The value of K that provides the maximum for this probability is the expected value of K.